# How to bind an event to leaflet layerswitcher without tying it to a layer?

Tags: leaflet

I am using Leaflet and am using the layerselector.

My problem is right now I define my layers like this:

```
var mymaps = {
 "Overlay 1": new L.geoJson(...)
 "Overlay 2": new L.geoJson(...)
}
L.control.layers(mymaps).addTo(mymap);
```

What I want is to be able to do:

```
var mymaps = {
 "Overlay 1": new L.geoJson(...)
 "Overlay 2": new L.geoJson(...)
 "Overlay 3": function() {
     console.log("Overlay 3 Selected");
     // call some other methods to pull in data and affect map
  }
}
```

How do I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `L.Control.Layers` the `baselayerchange`, `overlayadd` and `overlayremove` events fire on your map instance. In your case you need the `baselayerchange` event:

> Fired when the base layer is changed through the layer control.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-baselayerchange

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function (e) {
    console.log(e.name); // The name of the layer that was added or removed.
    console.log(e.layer); // The layer that was added or removed.
});
```